# Implement in C# a reference type that behaves like a value type

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I want to implement a 3D Vector type in C#. It will have overloaded operators for adding, subtracting, dot products, and so on. The usage patterns demand that it behave like a value type -- I want an assigment statement to copy the data, for example. So, for this (and other) reasons, it seems like I should use a struct.

But I also want to have a UnitVector type, to represent a vector with length 1. Presumably UnitVector should inherit from Vector. But inheritance only works if Vector and UnitVector are classes, not structs.

What should I do? Is there some way to make Vector and UnitVector classes behave like value types (as string does)? Or is there some possible scheme whereby Vector and UnitVector both independently implement some sort of IVector interface? Looking for suggested approaches.

Comment: *Is there some way to make Vector and UnitVector classes behave like value types (as string does)?* Make it immutable like `string` is?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight -- UnitVector isn't a constant. There are an infinite number of vectors with length = 1. So, I don't understand your suggestion.

Comment: @bubba: Likely the easiest way is to make the class immutable in general. So making an instance means it will _never, ever change_ after constructed. Applying the adding/subtracting/etc operators results in a new instance created. If you want to change another object which has this vector, you don't change a value on the vector, rather you replace the vector entirely with a newly constructed one.

Comment: @bubba There can be an infinite number of instances of an immutable class with the same value as well, they just can't change into an instance with a different value after they're created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to make a C# reference create a copy when a reference to that type is assigned. So if the `class UnitVector : Vector` approach is the way you want to go, copy-on-assignment is out.

However, @ta.speot.is already pointed you in a useful direction: If you make Vector an immutable class, you won't have to worry about copying it - it can't change anyway. If you also add implementations for `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` to get value equality semantics, this is a very good value type. I actually prefer classes like that to structs, though they end up being a lot more typing in C#.

```
public class Vector3d
{
    public readonly double X, Y, Z;

    public Vector3d(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        X=x; Y=y; Z=z;
    }

    public double Dot(Vector3d other)
    {
        return X*other.X + Y*other.Y + Z*other.Z;
    }

    public UnitVector3d Normalize()
    {
        return UnitVector3d.FromVector(this);
    }

    /* More operators like Times and Length, plus Equals and GetHashCode here */
}

public class UnitVector3d : Vector3d
{
    private UnitVector3d (double x, double y, double z) : base(x, y, z)
    {
        /* General constructor. Private so it can only be called by trusted
           functions because it could be used to construct non-unit UnitVectors */
    }

    public static UnitVector3d FromVector(Vector3d vec)
    {
        Vector3d normalized = vec.Times(1.0/vec.Length());
        return new UnitVector3d(normalized.X, normalized.Y, normalized.Z);
    }
}
```

The immutability is also a very good thing if you want to work with a `UnitVector` subclass. Why? Imagine the components of your `Vector` could change. Then the components of the `UnitVector` would be able to change in the same way (otherwise it would violate the Liskov substitution principle). But that means you could change a UnitVector in a way that changes its length. Oops. This is also known as the [Circle-Ellipse-Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem)
.

Making your `Vector` immutable avoids that problem. `UnitVector` could just be a subclass without any extra code which can be used to represent a vector that is known to have a length of 1 - you could even override the Length function there for optimization.

Comment: So, with this scheme, as I understand it, the only thing I lose is the ability to do simple direct assignments. I can't just write v2 = v1; I have to write v2 = v1.Copy or v2 = new Vector(v1), instead. Is that correct? What happens when I pass a vector to a function? And I guess I have to avoid having any public properties that change the value of the vector, too, right. If I want to have a public property "X" that allows me to write things like v.X = 7, then, internally the property setter has to make a new vector. Is that the idea?

Comment: Right now, I'm using a struct for Vector, and I don't have a UnitVector. My Vector is mutable. I keep reading that mutable stucts are evil, but I don't understand why.

Comment: "I have to write v2 = v1.Copy" -> No, you can just write `v2 = v1`. `Vector3d` is a normal reference type, so `v2` and `v1` will simply point to the same object. Same thing if you pass a `Vector3d` to a function - the function will work with the same object that you pass in. In fact, making a straight copy of an immutable value type is usually pointless because you could just use the original instead. Yes, you can't have anything in `Vector3d` that changes `X`, `Y` or `Z` outside of the constructor; you'll have to have your functions return new `Vector3d`s.

Comment: This should all be familiar, just look at `string`. You can't change a `string`, and methods like `string.ToUpper()` return a new `string`. Mutability isn't evil per se, but the fewer "moving parts" your program has, the easier it should be to understand it. Imagine passing a mutable `Vector3d` to a function which accidentally changes it in some calculation so your original value will be changed. Of course, structs protect against that in a different way, by having everyone use their own copy of the value.